# how to migrate wordpress blog website to a node based application?

Tags: wordpress, node.js

I had an already existing blog written in wordpress, which uses db for storing the posts. Now, I am removing the wordpress and writing my node application that just serves the page requested by the user. The problem I am facing is how do I convert the db to a page. Next, I am looking for any other option i.e. using the db and displaying it on the node application. Is there any easy option to do so?

Comment: **Why** are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy solution. You would have to re-implement Wordpress in node.